# How to show that linear regression coefficient estimators are mutually independent?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, independence, linear

I'm looking at linear regression with $y=\alpha+x\beta+e$.

About half-way down the page, https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/7/7.5 states that "a=$\hat \alpha$, $b=\hat \beta$, and $\hat \sigma^2$ are mutually independent".

I understand why $\hat \sigma^2$ is independent of the others, but I can't understand why $\hat \alpha$ and $\hat \beta$ are independent of each other.

Does someone have an explanation for this? Thanks.

Comment: The link cites a textbook that has a proof. I don't have this textbook. The link also says that the proof can be found in other mathematical statistics textbooks, but I can't find anything in my mathematical stats textbooks.